# Where in the caliburn micro bootstrapper can I inject already running code and close application

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I have the following code snippet.

```
bool ok;
var m = new System.Threading.Mutex(true, "Application", out ok);
if (!ok)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Another instance is already running.", ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion.ToString());
}
```

That should check if the application is already running. I was trying to inject it into the

```
protected override void StartRuntime()
```

but didnt know how to kill the app in the `if(!ok)` branch, is there a better place to inject this code to ensure the application only run once.

Comment: I'd say that `OnStartup` is the perfect method to override in the bootstrapper. Then you'd just do `Application.Current.Shutdown()`...

Comment: I did it in StartRuntime before it needed to be before the Configure Method.

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this.

```
protected override void StartRuntime()
{
    bool ok;
    var m = new System.Threading.Mutex(true, "Application", out ok);
    if (!ok)
    {
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }

    base.StartRuntime();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to check in the `Main()` method of the program, even before give WPF (or whatever) a chance to initialize. If the check returns that the application can start, then you create the  `Application` object and make it `Run()`.